# Chrome storage listener is not triggered by content scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, content-script

I've defined a new content scripts Chrome extension and I would like my extension javascript file to listen on storage changes made by content scripts.

This is `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
      }
  ]
}
```

This is `popup.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script> 
  </head>
</html>
```

This is `popup.js`:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});
```

This is `script.js`:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'key': 'value'}, function(){});
chrome.storage.local.set({'key': 'other_value'}, function(){});  // modify a key value to trigger the event
```

I would like to have my extension html (`popup.html`) updated when values are updated in storage by the content script (`script.js`).

I'm not sure if this is possible or perhaps the correct way to communicate in this case is [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication).

Comment: If the popup is closed at the time that your `script.js` executes, nothing will happen. `onChanged` only fires while the page is opened when the change occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here in the end.

Comment: @Xan thanks, you are right about when popup is being closed nothing happens. I've updated my question to explain what I'm trying to get.

Comment: Still don't understand what your goal is. You will not be notified of any state changes between openings of popup. While the popup is closed, it _does not exist_, so you can't communicate with it.